# Why is the subscription not updating correctly, Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have two subscriptions in the application, each of them individually works correctly. But when I try to do an Update/Downgrade, problems arise:

1. I have two subscriptions in the application, each of them individually works correctly. But when I try to do an **Update/Downgrade**, problems arise:
   When I try to change one subscription to another, I get the correct window with changing the subscription and shows that the new subscription was purchased successfully, but when I check on Google Play, it shows only the one I bought first, after a while I try again, this time it does not appear replacement window, only the standard purchase window, the second one is bought without problems and both are visible in the Store. Maybe I have some wrong approach to updating, everything seems to be in its place otherwise, the window with the replacement would not be displayed correctly.
2. My **setSuccessfulScreen()** method, in **onPurchasesUpdated()**, works correctly on the first purchase, but it crashes with an error when I try to update the subscription:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED
```

I thought maybe the case in Binding, I replaced with findViewById(), it does not help, without this method there is no crash.
My subscription code:

```
    private fun buySubscription() {
        val skuList = ArrayList<String>()
        skuList.add("")
        skuList.add("")
        val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
        billingClient!!.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build()) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                when (subsFlag) {
                    MONTH -> {
                        if (!ProviderPreferences.isSubscribed()) {
                            billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[1]!!).build())
                        } else {
                            if (ProviderPreferences.getSubscribedType() == MONTH) {
                                billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[1]!!).build())
                            } else {
                                val updateParams = BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder().setOldSkuPurchaseToken(ProviderPreferences.getPurchaseToken()!!).setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED).build()

                                billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[1]!!).setSubscriptionUpdateParams(updateParams).build())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    YEAR -> {
                        if (!ProviderPreferences.isSubscribed()) {
                            billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0]!!).build())
                        } else {
                            if (ProviderPreferences.getSubscribedType() == YEAR) {
                                billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0]!!).build())
                            } else {
                                val updateParams = BillingFlowParams.SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder().setOldSkuPurchaseToken(ProviderPreferences.getPurchaseToken()!!).setReplaceSkusProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED).build()

                                billingClient!!.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList[0]!!).setSubscriptionUpdateParams(updateParams).build())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun purchases() {
        val acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener { billingResult -> }
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(App.getInstance()).enablePendingPurchases().setListener { billingResult: BillingResult, list: List<Purchase>? ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                val purchase = list!![0]
                handlePurchases(acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener, purchase)
                ProviderPreferences.saveSubscriptionType(subsFlag)
                ProviderPreferences.savePurchaseToken(list[0].purchaseToken)
                setSuccessfulScreen()
            }
        }.build()
        connectToGooglePlayBilling()
    }

    private fun handlePurchases(acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener: AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener?, purchase: Purchase) {
        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            ProviderPreferences.saveSubscription(true)
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged) {
                val acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken).build()
                billingClient!!.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun connectToGooglePlayBilling() {
        billingClient!!.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
            override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                billingClient!!.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS) { billingResult, list ->
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                connectToGooglePlayBilling()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setSuccessfulScreen() {
        group!!.visibility = View.GONE
        group2!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        subscribeBtn!!.visibility = View.GONE
        lottieAnimation!!.playAnimation()
    }
```

I am using the billing **v4 library**.
Please tell me what could be the reason, maybe something is wrong with the subscription change code, I have not worked with subscription renewal before. And what could be the reason for the crash.
Thank you in advance.